# Out of sample prediction through Neural Network

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network

I have a dummy dataset of 3 years of expenses of a company spread across different expense heads. For the Heads column, I have taken dummy variables. After grouping the data in order of dates, I have removed the year and month column.
Below is a sample,

```
Head Year  Month Expense StockPrice
A     2005  1      23      120
A     2006  2      23      121 
B     2006  3      1000    130
C     2006  4      1500    135 
C     2007  1      1400    125
```

I have setup a neural network model for regression and have fitted the same to my train and test data.
My X data is of the shape (4851,6) and y data is of the shape (4851,1). I have been able to get good results out of the model.

Now, I want to make out of sample prediction from the model for the next 5 months, giving a prediction of expenses over the future 5 months. How should I proceed with that ?

Model which I have fitted

```
model = Sequential()
#model.add(Dense(units = 1, input_dim = 5, activation = 'relu')) 

model.add(Dense(256, input_dim = 6,kernel_initializer='normal', activation = 'relu')) 
model.add(Dense(256, input_dim = 6,kernel_initializer='normal', activation = 'relu')) 
model.add(Dense(256, input_dim = 6,kernel_initializer='normal', activation = 'relu')) 
model.add(Dense(1, activation='linear'))
model.compile(loss = 'mean_absolute_error', optimizer = 'adam')
model.summary()

model.fit(x = X_train, y= y_train, epochs = 100, validation_data = (X_test, y_test
                                                                  ), verbose = 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try creating an `X` with the dates moved into the future and calling `model.predict(X)` on it?

Comment: Hi, I have updated the description of data. Sorry for any confusion. After grouping the data in order of dates, I have removed the year and month column. If I move the dates into the future, won't I have to account for independent variables like stock price and dummy variables.

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on what exactly you mean by "out of sample"

1. If you want to make predictions of `expenses` of next 5 months given that you have those 5 months features (6 per sample as your model is expecting) then yes you can do and the way to do it is to use the `predict` method of the model.
2. If you do not have those 6 features per sample of next 5 months then no you cannot do "out of sample" predictions because you will need those features on which your model is trained for the model to make prediction.